# Can you use Python to write Raw Json to Snowflake Stage

Tags: python, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use Python to write raw Json to Snowflake Stage. I've used Snowflake's PUT file://file.json.gz @stage but that implies I need to write the file temporary to disk or cloud storage before storing it on a stage. This process works, however, the data I am sending is not allowed to be stored in the Cloud.
Is there a way I can write files to the stage directly?
Or is this not possible with Snowflake at the moment?
Thank you

Comment: What is the source of this raw JSON?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This doc has a good diagram of a stage: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system.html. depending on the Cloud provider you are using (eg AWS, Azure) the file will be stored within their object store. So for AWS a stage is a Snowflake managed  S3  bucket. All files written to Snowflake live within the cloud, regardless of internal stages or actual tables.

Comment: We are calling an API and holding the response (JSON) in memory. We are looking to send this response that is a variable to Snowflake as a file in Stage.

Answer (score 3):

You can write JSON directly to a Snowflake stage using the `COPY` command and `PARSE_JSON` function.

```
create or replace stage MY_JSON_STAGE;

copy into @MY_JSON_STAGE/MY_FILE_NAME.json from 
(select parse_json(
$$
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$$)) file_format = (type = json);
```

With a bit of fancy footwork, it's possible to write any string to a Snowflake stage directly using only Snowflake SQL. In this example, the JSON is stringified. Because it's possible to do this using SQL, you can do this from a script, stored procedure, or any client including Python.

```
create or replace file format RAW_STRING
    compression = 'auto'
    field_delimiter = 'NONE'
    record_delimiter = 'NONE'
    skip_header = 0
    field_optionally_enclosed_by = 'NONE'
    trim_space = FALSE
    error_on_column_count_mismatch = FALSE
    escape = 'NONE'
    escape_unenclosed_field = 'NONE'
;
create or replace stage RAW_STRING;

copy into @RAW_STRING/MY_FILE_NAME.txt from 
(select
$$
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$$) file_format = (format_name = 'RAW_STRING');
```